# how to sync multiple UIKit accordions

Tags: javascript, vue.js, uikit, getuikit

I'm rendering UIKit accordions dynamically inside table rows and each one contains just one child (`li`) element. how can I sync these accordions so that when one of them is open, other ones get collapsed? just like the option `multiple: false`. it's a Vue app (in case you can provide a more specific answer).

Comment: read https://getuikit.com/docs/accordion#javascript and use events fired when item is shown, so others will be hidden. You can use toggle for all except of currently shown ..

Comment: Could you share your code for how you put an accordion inside each table row? I tried doing it, but my accordion only goes inside the first td instead of being applied the entire tr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is much better and more performant

`i` is index of the loop.
`prevAccordionIndex` is defined in Vue instance data and initially set to null. It is used to hold the index of previous (last) opened accordion so there's no need to loop through `$refs` to find the open accordion like previous answer.

All accordions are initially collapsed (closed).

```js
methods: {
    handleAccordionShow(index) {
        if (this.prevAccordionIndex !== null) {
            this.$uikit.accordion(this.$refs.categoryAccordion[this.prevAccordionIndex]).toggle(0, false)
            this.prevAccordionIndex = index
        } else {
            this.prevAccordionIndex = index
        }
    },
    handleAccordionHide(index) {
        this.prevAccordionIndex = this.prevAccordionIndex === index ? null : index
    }
}
```

```html
<ul ref="categoryAccordion" @beforeshow="handleAccordionShow(i)" @beforehide="handleAccordionHide(i)" uk-accordion>
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is how I could solve it:

`i` is the index of the loop

```js
toggleAccordion(i) {
  for (let j = 0; j < this.$refs.categoryAccordion.length; j++) {
    if (j === i) {
      continue
    }
    if (this.$refs.categoryAccordion[j].classList.contains('uk-open')) {
      this.uikit.accordion(this.$refs.categoryAccordion[j].parentNode).toggle(0, false)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul @show="toggleAccordion(i)" uk-accordion>
  <li ref="categoryAccordion">
    ...
  </li>
</ul>
```